# Converting an NSString to an Integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing

I'm parsing some XML which contains numbers that are formatted like `100,000+` as an NSString. I want to convert these values to integers that I calculate something with them. How can I do this since there's a "," and "+"?

Comment: NSInteger iValue = [NSStringObject integerValue];

Comment: is it always by , and/or + ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
NSMutableString* string = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"100,000+"];
[string replaceOccurencesOfString: @"\," withString: @"" options: 0 range: NSMakeRange(0, [string length] ) ];
[string replaceOccurencesOfString: @"\+" withString: @"" options: 0 range: NSMakeRange(0, [string length] ) ];

NSInteger intValue = [string integerValue];
```

Comment: Minor point, but if the '+' is always at the end of the string, you don't need to remove it. integerValue will scan up to the first invalid character.

Comment: Also it should be `replaceOccurrencesOfString`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always strip out characters you don't want:

```
[yourStringObject stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];
```

Then its as simple as:

```
[yourStringObject intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are they always formatted with the `+`? You can check the string for that symbol (or others you might have) and remove it, and convert it normally.

Here's some code:

```
NSString *value = @"100,100+";
unichar lastChar = [value characterAtIndex:value.length - 1];
if (lastChar < '0' || lastChar > '9') // check for any symbol
    value = [value substringToIndex:characterAtIndex:value.length - 1]; // remove it

value = [value stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."]; // in case intValue doesn't handle commas, not sure if necessary
NSInteger result = [value intValue];
```